# How to use this and that in daily conversation. For example: 'this' or 'that is a good question'

Tags: british-english

I'm a little confused about the usage of *that* and *this*.

For example: My teacher was giving out our predicted grade. When it was my turn, she said:"A, A*"

I asked "What does that mean?"

She said that "It means we think you will get an A* if you work hard enough"

Here, is the usage of 'that' correct? Or should I use 'this' instead? How am I able to tell?

Another example is when someone explains to me what a word means, I say "that actually makes a lot of sense" or should it be 'this'?

And also when I ask someone about something, should the other person say ''that or this is a good question" ?

Is there a common rule?

Comment: You probably know that we use _this_ when speaking of an object which is near to us and _that_ for one further away. You used _that_ correctly for something that another person said to you; _this_ would be used of something that you yourself say. "This is what I think." "Listen to this."

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, similarly if the assessment had been given out as a written document and the OP had gone to the teacher with the document for clarification they could say (pointing to the paper) "What does this mean?" becasue the information is near to them. However in that scenario either 'this' or 'that' would be acceptable.